# Word for being aware only of oneself

Tags: single-word-requests, is-it-a-word

I'm looking for a word that describes an entity having only knowledge of its own existence, but no one else's.

The closest I have now is autognostic, auto being "self" and gnostic being "having knowledge", but I think autognostic might just mean "self-aware" and not "exclusively aware of oneself".

Does such a word exist?

Comment: I guess *self-centred* is too mild ?

Comment: "Narcissistic"? After Narcissus, who fell in love with his own reflection.

Comment: This is not a duplicate! This one is about awareness, the other one about belief.

Answer (score -1):

***Solipsistic***

This is the adjectival form of *[Solipsism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solipsism)*, an idea from philosophy, that one can only be sure of one's own existence.

By extension, this has gained an additional meaning of an egocentrism so extreme that the person afflicted by it sort of forgets that the people around him exist.

Notice that [egocentric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egocentrism), the inability to distinguish between self and other, will also fit pretty well, and will leave fewer people scratching their heads in confusion.

I typically think of the occupant of Pointland from Edwin A. Abbott's *[Flatland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland)*:

> "It fills all Space," continued the little soliloquizing Creature, "and what It fills, It is. What It thinks, that It utters; and what It utters, that It hears; and It itself is Thinker, Utterer, Hearer, Thought, Word, Audition; it is the One, and yet the All in All. Ah, the happiness, ah, the happiness of Being!"

[Source](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/97)

Comment: This is a good answer, and seems close to what I was seeking, although I think a distinction here is that solipsism describes only believing in one's own existence with certainty, but I was hoping to find a word for only perceiving one's own existence. Would solipsism still fit?

Comment: @RasmusKallqvist I don't see such a distinction. (Un)certainty is not a requirement for solipsism.