# A single word for something that only knows of its own existence

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to describe something that knows only of its own existence? So it does not know there is anything else out there but itself, not even that there might be others like it.

Comment: Also, [Word for being aware only of oneself](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/519822/word-for-being-aware-only-of-oneself/519831#519831). Both give solipsist / solipsism etc. // But the term is one thing; what is actually meant by 'only aware of one's own existence' is another. _How_ 'aware'? Is this in the realms of SF? A human baby can't survive without help from other humans, for instance.

Comment: Mindless. You might ask on a psychology site.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the word "solipsism".

A "solipsist" is someone who believes that everything he/she experiences is a figment of his/her imagination.

Comment: Yes I thought of that too, however, that implies that he actually knows there is a world out there with which he can interact (even though he thinks it is made up). 
I am rather searching for something that is oblivious to the existence of anything else..